# I want to subtract a float from a chronos duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am measuring an time duration with the Chrono Library. I measure it like this:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<float> elapsed = finish - start;
```

This works, but now I am trying to subtract the duration from a float or a double(doesnt matter which) and let the thread sleep, like this:
frameTime is the float/double.

```
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(frameTime - elapsed));
```

Doesnt that work or am I doing something wrong here? Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

What is the `frameTime`? Nanoseconds, hours? To disambiguate this you need to convert from a number to the duration:

```cpp
auto const frameTime = std::chrono::milliseconds(some_number_here);
this_thread::sleep_for(frameTime - elapse));
```

Notice, that you don't have to convert the subtraction result to `chrono::miliseconds` anymore. You can even substract a different units like hours - minutes